# Failed app download off of Amazon Appstore is taking up internal phone storage

Tags: internal-storage, storage

I tried downloading an app off of the Amazon Appstore(probably my first mistake), however after it was complete it said there was an error, the app was nowhere to be found, and then it started to download from the beginning. This process repeated until I had no more internal storage on my phone. The frustrating thing is that I have a 64gb microSD card, where most of my apps are stored. I've already deleted several apps that are on my phone storage. There is almost 6gb of miscellaneous files, not sure if this is unreal or not but it is taking up most of the storage. Please help me figure out how to clear up internal phone space, and how to solve the mystery of the redownloading invisble app.[image]

Comment: First- your SD card has nothing to do with installing apps (other than side-loading). Your phone storage is where apps are downloaded to install. Second- which app are you trying to install? I tried several, several times to download "Monument Valley" from the Amazon Appstore. It would take forever to download (over 200mb) and would then say that the app was not installed. This problem is caused by the Amazon Appstore not having the updated version of the app. Third- tap on "Miscellaneous Files" and see what's taking up space. It's time to start cleaning up files.

Comment: @paulmz I was trying to download Minecraft: the Story Mode. And I have checked out my "Miscellaneous Files" before but I'm not sure what to keep, delete, or mess with to reduce size.

Comment: Your Miscellaneous is still high. What are your top ten items in there? We can help figure it out.

Comment: @paulmz 1. .youversion 2. Snapchat 3. Photo Grid 4. Hnc 5. yahoo 6. roidapp 7. ktplay 8. bmwgroup 9. photo editor 10. requests.log

Comment: Well, so far the only thing in your list that matches my list is the requests log, which is only 310kb on mine. Here are things to consider: do you need and regularly use these memory-hungry apps? Have you cleared the cache for these apps? Do any of the apps have a setting to store their data on the external SD card? Most of them appear to be apps that can be uninstalled and not system apps. If you don't use any of them, then uninstall it. Make sure to clear the data for an app when uninstalling, too.

Comment: I have cleared the cache multiple times before. And regarding app usage: I used to have several more apps on my phones storage that I deleted recently. Something is just taking up way too much space after that download. I'm also not sure if I can store the app data on my SD card, but can't see an option for it anywhere.